# Native vs HTML5 mobile app for image processing?

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile

I am building a **mobile app** which is heavy in terms of processing. I am not sure whether html5 mobile frameworks like **phonegap/titanium** let me do **processor/memory intensive tasks** like image recognition , image stitching on the fly.
If yes , is it recommended to use **html5/js or to go native**? a point-wise comparison between these two options will help me a lot!

Thanks

Comment: have you tried your process on browser? check out your performance and think, it ll be on a mobile device.

Comment: i havent executed the code as such. I am yet to finish the code. But my question is, for applying standard image stitching algorithms is it possible to do it using sencha? or native is the way to go?
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vtcreator.android360&hl=en there are android apps which do panorama using image stitching.